# Error in python runserver command

Tags: python

I'm working on MobSf installation.  This is what I get when I launch the command:

`python manage.py runserver`

It results in the following error:

`Unable to parse folder from binskim nuget installation`

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you ask the MobSF guys ? https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF#contribution-feature-requests--bugs

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug I guess. Please use the latest master.